# Coded UI Test - Working with File Picker Cotnrol

Tags: c#-4.0, coded-ui-tests

I am writing coded ui test for windows store apps. The application basically opens a text file.

So I am able to automated till the point

1 -> Launch App -> 2 -> Click on open file buton

Then comes this screen (File picker for windows store app):

[image]

Now I want to go to D:\ABC\test.txt and open test.txt file. How to automate this part?

Answer (score 0):

Whoa!!!! Finally I figured it out.

Coded UI Test for windows store apps works only with XAML controls.

Controls such as Start Menu, File Picker, Charms (e.g. settings charms) are not XAML control.

They fall under the catgory of DirectUIControl

So I created this DirectUIControl manually and added to my UI map and it worked perfectly.

E.g.

```
DirectUIControl ctrl = new DirectUIControl(//mention the parent control from them);
ctrl.SearchProperties[DirectUIControl.PropertyNames.AutomationId] = ""; //set the automation id. In my case it was the path to file
ctrl.WindowTitle.Add(//Title of the window, window in which they existed");
```

And now they are ready. You can use your Mouse.Click or Gesture.Tap on these added DirectUIControl(s)

- Priyank